# jQuery Mobile changePage not working

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to link to the following html page using

```
$.mobile.changePage( "myPage.html", { transition: "slide"} );
```

However, it's not working. The page will load however the alert box with the spinning cirlce and "loading" message never disappears and the page never fully loads in its css content. Can anybody see why based on the above call and the html below? Thanks

**HTML Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
  <title>Sign up</title> 

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./signup.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.js"></script>

  <script>   
   // Global declarations - assignments made in $(document).ready() below
    var hdrMainvar = null;
    var contentMainVar = null;
    var ftrMainVar = null;
    var contentTransitionVar = null;
  </script>

</head> 
<body> 

<!-- Page starts here -->
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="page1">

      <div data-role="header" id="hdrMain" name="hdrMain" data-nobackbtn="true">
        <h1>Classroom Tempo</h1>
      </div>

          <div data-role="navbar">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="" data-icon="" data-transition="fade" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Sign-In</a></li>
            <li><a href="survey_SignUp.html" rel="external" data-icon="" data-transition="fade">Sign-Up</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>


      <div data-role="content" id="contentMain" name="contentMain"> 

      <form id="form1">

      <div id="optionSliderDiv" data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="optionSlider">How Many Options?</label>
        <input type="range" name="optionSlider" id="optionSlider" value="2" min="2" max="25" data-highlight="true" />
      </div>

      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
      <legend>Numbers or Letters?:</legend>
          <input type="radio" name="numbersOrLetters" id="Numbers" value="Numbers" checked="checked" />
          <label for="Numbers">Numbers</label>

          <input type="radio" name="numbersOrLetters" id="Letters" value="Letters"  />
          <label for="Letters">Letters</label>
    </fieldset>

      <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
        // Assign global variables
           hdrMainVar = $('#hdrMain');
          contentMainVar = $('#contentMain');
          ftrMainVar = $('#ftrMain');
          contentTransitionVar = $('#contentTransition');

          sliderValue = $('#optionSlider');
          surveyDescriptionVar = $('#SurveyDescription')

          form1Var = $('#form1');
          confirmationVar = $('#confirmation');
          contentDialogVar = $('#contentDialog');

          hdrConfirmationVar = $('#hdrConfirmation');
          contentConfirmationVar = $('#contentConfirmation');
          ftrConfirmationVar = $('#ftrConfirmation'); 
          inputMapVar = $('input[name*="_r"]');

          hideContentDialog();
          hideContentTransition();
          hideConfirmation();
        }); 

        $('#buttonOK').click(function() {
          hideContentDialog();
          //hidePasswordMisMatch();
          showMain();
          return false;      
        });


        $('#form1').submit(function() {
            var err = false;
            var passwordError = false;

            // Hide the Main content
            hideMain();

            console.log(sliderValue.val());


            // If validation fails, show Dialog content
            if(err == true){  

            console.log("we've got an issue");
              showContentDialog();

              return false;
            }        

            $('input[name=OnOff]').each(function() { 
                onOffValue = $('input[name=OnOff]:checked').val();
            })

            $('input[name=numbersOrLetters]').each(function() { 
                numbersOrLetters = $('input[name=numbersOrLetters]:checked').val();
            })

            console.log(onOffValue);
            console.log(numbersOrLetters);
            // If validation passes, show Transition content
            showContentTransition();

            // Submit the form
            $.post("http://url", form1Var.serialize(), function(data){

              console.log(data);

              hideContentTransition();
              showConfirmation();
            });        
            return false;      
        });   


      </script>
    </div> <!-- page1 -->

<!-- Page ends here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you use the latest jQuery Mobile? I have a feeling that the old version doesn't support the option object.

Comment: you have saved me so much time. please add this as an answer so I can gladly upvote/mark as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$.mobile.changePage` API has undergone some changes from version 1.0 alpha 4 and 1.0.1 of jQuery Mobile. The syntax you are using with option object is of the newer version of jQuery Mobile (at least from 1.0.1).